# PHPUnit : Set value to a protected attribute from abstract class

Tags: php, phpunit, abstract-class

I have this abstract class:

```
abstract class AbstractFilter implements FilterInterface
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected string $filterExpression;

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFilterExpression(): string
    {
        return $this->filterExpression;
    }
}
```

I wanted to test `getFilterExpression` function on PHPUnit, my test file:

```
class AbstractFilterTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * @return void
     */
    public function testGetFilterExpression(): void
    {
        $exceptedResult = 'foo';
        $mock = $this->getMockForAbstractClass(
            AbstractFilter::class,
            [],
            '',
            false,
            true,
            true,
            ['filterExpression']
        );

        $mock->expects(self::once())->method('filterExpression')->willReturn($exceptedResult);

        $result = $mock->getFilterExpression();
        $this->assertIsString($result);
    }
}
```

I have this error:

> Error : Typed property
> Lib\Common\DbAccess\Filter\AbstractFilter::$filterExpression must not
> be accessed before initialization

Because I can't set a value for `filterExpression` property.

Is it possible to assign a value to the `filterExpression` property or do I have to use a concrete test class that extends the abstract class to do my tests (which I don't want to do)?

Thank's in advance,

Comment: I would say to extend that class with a fake class (test class) so you can set whatever you want. You should do that so you can test all the abstract stuff, and then you don't exactly need to test it again on a real class when you test that real class, think this like "Any class that wants to extend this abstract, will have the abstract logic working 100%"

Comment: That's what I did, thank's :)